# Receive Array in Proto RPC

Tags: go, rpc, proto

I build a REST service generated by a proto file with rpc.
I succeed receiving a single event as follows:

```
rpc PostEvent(Event) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/myEP"
      body: "*"
    };
  }
```

and it works - converts a json object to Event{} struct.

My question is, how to do the same thing when I want to receive an array of Event{}s.

This could work:

```
message EventsWrapper {
  repeated Event events = 1;
}
rpc PostEvents(EventsWrapper) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/myEP"
      body: "*"
    };
  }
```

But then it will expect a json like:

> {"events":[{},..,{}]}

While I receive only:

> [{},..,{}]

I don't control the way I receive the call. Any ideas how I can tweak my code to handle such an array call?

Comment: According to the protobuf standard, gRPC services can only take message types as parameters, and message types can only be represented as JSON objects. So, at least per the spec, you cannot use PB to define a service that takes a JSON array directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to accept a JSON array, and the gRPC transcoding implementation you use supports it, you can use the `body` attribute to specify a repeated field that is mapped to the request body, instead of using `*`.

Quoting from the [Google HttpRule API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/service-management/reference/rpc/google.api#special-notes):

> If an API needs to use a JSON array for request or response body, it can map the request or response body to a repeated field. However, some gRPC Transcoding implementations may not support this feature.

> `body` — The name of the request field whose value is mapped to the HTTP request body, or * for mapping all request fields not captured by the path pattern to the HTTP body, or omitted for not having any HTTP request body.

In other words, you would define your service as:

```proto
message EventsWrapper {
  repeated Event events = 1;
}
// ...
  rpc PostEvents(EventsWrapper) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/myEP"
      body: "events"
    };
  }
```

I believe this is supported by at least [gRPC-Gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) (since [PR #712](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/pull/712)) and likely also [Envoy Proxy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/)'s [gRPC-JSON transcoder](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/grpc_json_transcoder_filter). The latter also supports translating between JSON arrays and streaming gRPC methods, so if you define an `rpc PostEvent(stream Event) returns (google.protobuf.Empty)` method, Envoy will expect an array of `Event` objects in the request (and possibly even stream the translated messages as they arrive).